# datatables thead and tfoot doesn't match with tbody

Tags: html, css, datatables, responsive

i have a problem with my datatables (use bootstrap). Why the thead & tfoot don't match with tbody - see it on my uploadet picture.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="table-layout: fixed;overflow:hidden;">
```

[image]

what can i do does thead and tfoot have 100%?

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 1084px; padding-right: 17px;">
```

Why dataTables_scrollHeadInner have a padding-right from 17px? i have found the definition in datatables.js

Comment: Having some actual table code would help a lot.

Comment: Provide full table structure code !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the datatable markup in the HTML and not programmatically make sure you have the same number of th elements as you do td elements within the body. But also, if this isn't the case, show us your markup and js and we can dig further.